# Regarding tree view, is it possible to give a specific color to a node?

Tags: javascript, echarts

As the question state, will like to know if I can set the color for individual nodes in echarts tree view.

If not, is there a way to do it problematically?

[image: example tree view from echarts]

For example I want, physics in layer 2 to be blue color, and scale to be yellow color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can redefine node visual way you want. In general this options can be setup from data. Please [look at docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.data) where this is explained as detailed as possible. I also made a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2hauto3p/) on jsfiddle:

```js
data: [{
        "name": "flare",
        "children": [{
          "name": "analytics",
          itemStyle: {  // <--------- this
            borderColor: 'blue'
          },
          "children": [{
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "value": 3938,
                itemStyle: { // <--------- this
                  borderColor: 'blue'
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "CommunityStructure",
                "value": 3812,
                itemStyle: {  // <--------- this
                  borderColor: 'yellow'
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                "value": 6714
              },
              {
                "name": "MergeEdge",
                "value": 743
              }
            ]
          }]
        }]
      }]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the same thing but it doesnt seems to work

Comment: The demo is working perfectly — http://jsfiddle.net/2hauto3p/

Comment: With latest echarts version this code doesnt seems to work

Comment: Link to official help above. Just adapt it to your code or create new question.